# AJAX server calls on a JSF-centric app

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsf-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate JQuery with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918682/integrate-jquery-with-jsf)

I'm building a JSF 2 application. I wanted to integrate it with jQuery, e.g.:

```
$.getJSON(contextPath + '/something', function(data) {
// ...
});
```

I need `contextPath/something` to return data in JSON. How can I do it?

I know I can assign another servlet to this URL, but this approach does not seem to scale well. One could use a more scalable approach with a front end controller (e.g. Spring Web MVC), but I really wanted to write this in Java Enterprise stack. What other options are there?