# JSF 2.0 timer component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm looking for a component that counts down a specific duration on the client side (e.g. to display the remaining time until an auction finishes). The component does not need to necessarily perform an action when the timer is timed out. It should basically print the timer in a human readable form, e.g. 1 hour 2 minutes 23 seconds and update the timer without server requests.

I know that this can be done somehow in JavaScript. What I'm looking for is ready-made component or an easy way to realize this (without much implementation effort).

Thanks,
Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) component. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918682/integrate-jquery-with-jsf) gives an answer on JSF jQuery integration.